# IF/ELSE $(document).ready Statement

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write some jQuery to remove the default selected option of a select box once. Currently the `$("#edit-field option:selected").remove(); removed = true;};` Works, but I'm having trouble putting it into a if/else statement.

```
$(document).ready (function remove() {
"use strict";
var removed = false;
if (removed = false) {
$("#edit-field option:selected").remove(); removed = true;}; else {
remove();}}
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with my code?

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, you want `==` for comparison ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is a very common beginner error.

`=` **always** assigns a value, you cannot use it in comparisons. Use `==` or `===` to compare values. So the simple fix would be:

```
if(removed === false)
```

BUT... comparisons like `if (x == true) ...` or `if (x == false) ...` are an anti-pattern. Don't do that. `if (x) ...` or `if (!x) ...` is enough.

Also, your entire code is superfluous. Don't keep a global variable that stores whether you have removed something. That's not necessary.

jQuery will not produce an error when you try to remove something twice, or try to remove something that is not there at all. This is *much* better:

```
$(document).ready(function remove() {
    $("#edit-field option:selected").remove();
});
```

Comment: The code sample you provided is the exact same as what I started with but for some reason jQuery was removing ALL values in the select box one by one and it still is. With you help though I've solved my problem by using this `$(document).ready(function remove() {
    $("#edit-field option:selected").remove(":contains('Text in field')");
});`

Answer (score 2):

```
if (removed = false)
```

This is wrong, you are reassigning the value of false to the variable.

```
if(removed === false)
```

Is the comparative operator you should be using

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp